# Polymer 0.5.5: conditional template and/or template dynamic reference inside core-list

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a polymer 0.5.5 core-list, that displays some items from an AJAX call. Inside the core-list, if I have a template, it works fine and displays my items as intended. What I'd like to do though is reuse the same core-list to show a list of different items, that should be bound to a different template. I can't for the life of me get that to work.

I have tried having two templates with a if attribute that use reverse conditions (`if="{{model.attribute}}"` and `if="{{!model.attribute}}"`), but both conditions seem to always evaluate to false.

I have tried templates with a ref attribute that is calculated via a conditional (`ref="{{model.attribute?'template1':'template2'}}"`) or via a variable in my element (`ref="{{mode}}"`), that I change before calling the AJAX request again.

Nothing of that works. In the best case, only the first template is used. In other instances, nothing appears. On other combinations of code, it's worse: I "seem" to get the right initial template but some things don't work, as if only a partial model object was passed. I have a filter on the data, and in some weird cases less data is shown that should be.

I have the sinking feeling this type of dynamic templating doesn't play well with core-list. Has anybody achieved that effect? Basically I just want one list that can display two types of item and switch templates accordingly. Since the switch is done programmatically, I can do things in code if need be, but I'm not sure what I can change in the templates this way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<div vertical layout fit style="overflow:auto;">
<h1>asd</h1>
<core-list data="{{ list_data }}" id="core_list_ps">
    <template>
        <div class="item">
         <!--  NOTE!
         All list data, as custom elements, must go inside the 'item' here. -->
        <template if="{{model.list1}}">
                  <my-list1
                          id="list1_id"
                          route="{{route}}"
                          list1_data='{{model}}'
                   ></my-list1>
         </template>   
         <template if="{{model.list2}}">
                  <my-list2
                          id="list2_id"
                          route="{{route}}"
                          list2_data='{{model}}'
                   ></my-list2>
         </template>   
         </div>
    </template>
</core-list>
```

So, based on which data is passed to the core-list model - different custom element is used for rendering the elements.

Also flatiron-director is used to filter the data(list1/list2) based on the route.

Comment: All simply! The intermediate div solves all the issues I had. Inside that div then dynamic refs work also. Thanks a million.

Comment: This is an ugly solution.